# Mysql import of non-csv data with field identifiers

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to import a non-csv data file into MySQL.

1) The data fields are newline delimited, and the field identifier is at the start of each line.

2) Some fields have multiple entries

3) Not every record has every field populated

4) Some blank lines exist inside fields and need to be filtered out

5) Records are generally delimited by blank lines, but also by "Number X"

Here's an example of the file showing an example of three records as they appear

```
Number  1
ARTIST  BOOM JEFF=SINGER
    BACKING MUSICIANS=BAND
COMP  BOOM JEFF
DATE  1980
TIME  3.23
FIELD3  FRONT ROW
NOTE  LIVE RECORDING


Number  2
ARTIST  JOHN LEE=VOCAL
COMP  JOHN LEE
TIME  4.20
ID  000000230682
PUBLISHER  BLAHBLAH
FIELD3  DAY I RODE THE TRAIN

Number  3
ARTIST  BURT DAN=NARRATOR
     JOHNS RY=DRUMS
     STUDIO BAND=ORCHESTRA
     FREE DAN=DIRECTOR
COMP  JOHNS RY
DATE  1934
DUR  2.32
ID  000055332
PUBLISHER  WEEWAH
SHELF  86000002
FIELD3  EVE OF THE WAR
NOTE  FROM HE NARRATION "NO MORE THAT IN

       THE FIRST YEARS OF THE SEVENTEENTH CENTURY .."
```

What's the best way to import this data into MySQL?

Can LOAD DATA INFILE be used to read it in? Or should I write a script to strip the field identifiers and convert it to csv format which can then be read in using LOAD DATA INFILE?

Comment: Where is this from? Are that md3 / id3 tags or some other "well known" format? Then it would be much easier to try to convert that in to a proper csv first and then load it in to a DB?

Comment: It's a proprietary format, so there is more data than exists in a standard format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see, your best bet is a script that would parse the data line by line with a script similar to the following (using php):

```
$lines=explode("\n",file_get_contents('file.name'));

$record=null;
//go through all the lines
foreach($lines as $line) {
  //if the line is not empty, add the field to the record
  if(trim($line)) {
    //I am only processing the field name-you'll have to do the same for equal signs
    $pos = strpos($line, ' ');
    $fieldName=substr($line,0,$pos;
    $fieldValue=substr($line,$pos+1);
    $record[$fieldName]=$fieldValue;
  }
  //if it is a blank line and we have a record, save it
  else if ($record) {
    //insert the record into the database
    insertRecord($record);
    //empty the record as the next line is a new record
    $record=null;
  }
}

function insertRecord($record) {
//to do implement an sql insert statement
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would rather use `sed`  to convert those to `INSERT .. SET ...` statements like:

```
INSERT INTO RECORDS SET 
ARTIST="BOOM JEFF=SINGER~BACKING MUSICIANS=BAND" ,
COMP="BOOM JEFF" ,
DATE="1980" ,
TIME="3.23" ,
FIELD3="FRONT ROW" ,
NOTE="LIVE RECORDING"
```

replacing in-record newlines with `~` for example and after that analyse data with the help of SQL.